# Spark program cannot open SQL Server context?

Tags: sql-server, scala, apache-spark

In the file `main.scala`,

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import java.sql._

object ConnTest extends App {
  val conf = new SparkConf()
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf.setAppName("Test").setMaster("local[*]"))
  val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

  sc.stop()
}
```

However, the `sbt run` got the following error.

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to C:\Users\user1\IdeaProjects\sqlServer\target\scala-2.11\classes...
[error] C:\Users\user1\IdeaProjects\sqlServer\src\main\scala\main.scala:9: type SQLContext is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql
[error]   val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
[error]                                             ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed May 11, 2017 6:11:47 PM
```

Comment: First, what are your dependencies - sql must be explicitly set? Also you shouldn't use sbt run for spark, but spark-submit instead.

Comment: I should use SBT compile the code first. Maybe I shouldn't use "run"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Spark 2 which has single entry point `SparkSession`. you can create `SQLContext` and `SparkContext` as

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

val sc = sparkSession.sparkContext
val sqlC = sparkSession.sqlContext
```

Include the dependency for spark core and spark sql

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.1.1"
```

Comment: Do I need to download and jdbc driver for SQL server?

Comment: Spark does not include any JDBC drivers, you are responsible for providing them in the application bundle or other classpath item.

Comment: @ShankarKoirala No I'm reading data from Microsoft Sql Server.

Comment: You need to add and bundle the jar yourself. you can also provide the jar during spark-submit

Answer (score 0):

**Your class path is correct, please carefully check you maven or sbt configure**

In maven, you should add this specific **dependency**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

sbt is similar too, **if you want to add this dependency at compile time and package an uber jar with it**.

But **sometime** the spark-core jar is **provided by the cluster at runtime**, if it is **in this case, you can adjust the scope value at you convenient**, maybe `provided`.

What must to be said is that sbt or maven is just **dependency control tool**, not relevant to spark's execution, you should get your jar package upload on the cluster, and use the spark-submit program to run it!

**Please see the community document of the spark example, and have a try**:

http://spark.apache.org/examples.html

Good Luck!